# Use Linux netbook to play youtube videos on a Mac

Tags: youtube

I have a Mac with Mac OSX leopard running and Firefox connected to a big external monitor. I would like to play YouTube videos in int, at full screen.

I would like to sit on the sofa, and with a netbook that runs Ubuntu, been able to tell the Mac to play the videos I want.

Is it possible?

Comment: > Is it possible? Yes.

Comment: Enable screen sharing on the Mac (set a password), and then use a VNC client to connect to the Mac and you can control it remotely. VNC is a keyboard/mouse sharing technology, so you can use the keyboard and mouse on your netbook like they were connected to your Mac.

Comment: no, this is not what I am looking for. I would like to pre-cue the videos I want to see on te linux netbook at the same time they are played on the mac at full screen, sort of DJ-ing